# Like Icon colour on click

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

I've created a "like" feature with an icon that will be added in product card.

I need to make the icon stay red once it's been clicked, but it also needs to display the animation at the same time.

By the looks of it they're overlapping each other and ones cancelling the other out.

```css
.heart{
    font-size: 24px!important;
    color: #fff;
}

/* PUSH HOVER EFFECT */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.hvr-push {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
}

.hvr-push:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-push;
  animation-name: hvr-push;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* CHANGE ICON ON HOVER */

.change-icon > .fa + .fa,
.change-icon:hover > .fa {
    display: none;
    
}

.change-icon:hover > .fa + .fa {
    display: inherit;
    color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span class="change-icon">
     <i class="hvr-push heart fa fa-heart-o"></i>
     <i class="hvr-push heart fa fa-heart"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include the css for icon, your snippet is not working

Comment: Can you add any cdn for that i class?

Comment: It wouldn't let me add all the code so I create a codepen instead, is this okay? https://codepen.io/kellett/pen/dJXxYJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
/* when a user clicks, toggle the 'is-animating' class */
$(".heart").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
  $(this).toggleClass('liked');
});

/*when the animation is over, remove the class*/
$(".heart").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});
```

```css
.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image:url( 'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:2900%;
}

.heart:hover {
  background-position:right;
}

.liked {
  background-position:right;
}

.is_animating {
  animation: heart-burst .8s steps(28) 1;
}

@keyframes heart-burst {
  from {background-position:left;}
  to { background-position:right;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Darshit,  Sorry my coding isn't the best... Do I need to remove any of the older code for this? also where should I be adding this.

Comment: just replace you css and html and jquery as given in my snippent. :)

Comment: Hi Darshit, By any chance do you know why this is spacing showing at the bottom of this card? I can't seem to work out where it's coming from. https://codepen.io/kellett/pen/dJXxYJ

Comment: there is problem in section and row class due to padding bottom and top and margin in row class